# Fabric Digits oauth authentication in PHP

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, twitter-digits

I've got an app which works with Digits as authentication. 
Client-side works perfectly, but I'm not able to make the server user authentication through oAuth. 
My server is developed with Laravel, so it's PHP.
My endpoint is under https, so everything should be ready to make the call.

Comment: Got any updates on this?

Comment: Yes, i solved! the problem was Digits header that wasn't set correctly. I'll add my code as answer, so you can get your answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

I solved by myself!

Here's the code that makes correctly the authentication through Digits O-Auth.

The function that makes authentication is inside an AuthManager class and I call in this way:

```
$obj = AuthManager::verifyUser($request->header('X-Auth-Service-Provider'),$request->header("X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization"));
```

And here's the function that makes the magic:

```
public static function verifyUser ($xAuthServiceProvider, $xVerifyCredentialsAuthorization)
{

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, $xAuthServiceProvider);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-length: 0',
        'Content-type: application/json',
        'Authorization: '.$xVerifyCredentialsAuthorization,
    ));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $content = curl_exec($curl);
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $obj = json_decode($content, true);

    return $obj;
}
```

If you have any problem, don't hesitate to write here!

**EDIT WITH EXAMPLE FUNCTION ABOUT HOW TO GET DATA FROM O-AUTH**

```
public function authenticate (Request $request)
{

    $obj = AuthManager::verifyUser($request->header('X-Auth-Service-Provider'),$request->header("X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization"));
    if(isset($obj["errors"]))
    {
        return "error!";
    }
    $digits_token =  $obj["access_token"]["token"];
    $digitsId = $obj["id"];


    /*
        the variables above are returned by O-auth server-server authentication
    */
}
```

Comment: How would you then know that the inputted number is for an existing user in your dataserver (let's assume that you're using mysql)?

Comment: Also who is your client? Is this a web client or a mobile client?

Comment: My client is an iOS app right now, but it works perfectly also for Android or web app. When I get the correct answer from digits O-auth server-server authentication, I check if exists this digits ID in my database, if not I save it. My whole app works checking this digitsId, because it's sure that an user has only one digits ID

Comment: Hmmm. CAn you update your answer to show how you will call an endpoint to your server after handling the success on Digits OAuth side?

Comment: On second thought, will it be more simpler if I skip the curl part and let the mobile client do all the work? Since mobile client will just do the authentication. They will just pass the `digitsUserId` to the server and do a log-in from there?

Comment: No, because there could be a man-in-the-middle between client and server. In this way, you are 100% sure.

Comment: Hello @Bellots I'm having problems with trying out cannonball-web demo (https://github.com/twitterdev/cannonball-web). I've set the consumer key and secret and the website url in the fabric dashboard but always end up with the "something is wrong page". What am I missing?

Comment: So is web-based app? Are you trying authentication client-server or server-server?

Comment: Im using your code, but I keep getting 502 error on curl_exec. Any ideas?

Comment: I want to implement it for asp.net web api any link? previous code is in php and now i'm moving it to asp.net webapi. comment any useful link or code sample. thanks :)